# Adding 2 inputted numbers in Assembly using NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I have done my best to explain all of my thought process when adding these two numbers. However, upon running the resulting executable I end up with 
"Sum is: j" which is clearly wrong. Additionally, it seems that no matter which inputs I give the sum stays as "j" so there must be something awfully wrong.

I believe this code should work but my understanding is clearly flawed.
Where should I start in fixing this? I just recently began learning assembly.

```
section .data ;line 1
    msg db  "Sum is: "
    len equ $ - msg

section .bss
    num1 resb 1
    eol1 resb 1
    num2 resb 1
    eol2 resb 1
    sum resb 2

section .text
global _start

print_int:
    mov eax, 4  ;defining routine print_int
    mov ebx, 1  ;file descriptor (stdout)
    int 0x80    ;system call number (sys_write)
    ret     ;return back

_start:
    ;Read and store user input for num1
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num1
mov edx, 2  ;2 bytes of info 
int 80h

mov byte [eol1], 0xA ; value of first end of line

;Read and store user input for num2
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num2
mov edx, 2  ;2 bytes of info 
int 80h

mov byte [eol2], 0xA ;value of 2nd end of line

;Add num1 and  num2
mov eax, num1
sub eax, '0'    ;this is so that the value in 3 is set to 3 because
        ;'3' and '0' actually are ASCII values
mov ebx, num2
sub ebx, '0'
add eax, ebx    ;Move the sum of 0x3 and 0x4 into eax
add eax, '0'    ;Set eax to be the ASCII value for the result of the sum


mov [sum], eax  ;Set this ascii value of the sum to sum 

mov ecx, msg    ;Move msg ('Sum is: ') into eax
mov edx, len    ;Move len (length of msh) into edx
call print_int  ; call routine print_int above

;load sum to to be printed
mov ecx, sum
mov edx, 2 ;size in bytes of sum
call print_int


mov eax, 1  ;system call number (sys_exit)
xor ebx, ebx
int 0x80    ;line 43
```

Comment: You should use a debugger like GDB to look at what is happening as the program executes.

Comment: But I'll give you a hint `mov eax, num1` and `mov ebx, num2` move the addresses of `num1` and `num2` into eax and ebx, not the values they point at. `mov [sum], eax` moves the 4 bytes in _EAX_ to `sum`. but sum is only defined to be 2 bytes long, and that poses a problem.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks, I am working on fixing what you first mentioned. However, for the latter problem, could I then just do mov [sum], ax? I am not sure if this would be the two desired bits (or the two undesired ones).

Comment: `ax` is "low" 16 bits of 32 bit `eax`, i.e. if you count values from 0 to 65535 (unsigned 16 bit integers), the `ax` is "equivalent" to `eax`. For values above 65536 there's some bit in upper 16 bits of `eax` set, so `ax` is only truncated part of `eax` (`ax` = `eax mod 65536`). So as long as your result fits into 16 bits, the `mov [sum],ax` is proper solution. If you want 32 bit integer results, you will have to expand reserved memory for `sum`, like `sum resb 4` or `sum resd 1`. (also you are talking about bYtes (32 bits = 4 bytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program operates on 2 single digit numbers inputted by the user.

---

> ```
> mov eax, num1
> mov ebx, num2
> ```

On NASM, this will move the address of these variables in those registers. What you want is the contents! You need to write the square brackets.
But wait - since the input has only a single byte of information, you should read the data in the byte-sized registers `AL` and `BL`.

```
mov al, [num1]
mov bl, [num2]
```

All subtractions and additions then will also have to use these smaller sizes.

```
sub al, '0'  ;From character '0'-'9' to number 0-9
sub bl, '0'
add al, bl
add al, '0'  ;From number 0-9 to character '0'-'9'
```

The character in `AL` is what you want to print. Easiest is to first append the newline 0xA in the `AH` register and then write `AX` in the memory.

```
mov ah, 0xA
mov [sum], ax
```

---

All the above is correct whenever the sum of the 2 single digit numbers was less than 10.
Imagine what will happen when you input e.g. numbers 5 and 8 ?

The sum (13) would require 2 characters leaving no room for the extra newline character. The largest sum will come from adding 9 and 9 (18).
Best re-define "sum" as `sum resb 3`.

Then write the following:

```
 mov al, [num1]
 mov bl, [num2]
 sub al, '0'
 sub bl, '0'
 add al, bl

 mov edx, 2       ;String length if single digit sum
 mov ecx, sum     ;Address of sum
 cmp al, 10
 jb  SingleDigit

 mov byte [ecx], '1'
 inc ecx          ;Move to position for the units/newline
 inc edx          ;String length if double digit sum
 sub al, 10       ;Only keep the units

SingleDigit:
 add al, '0'      ;From number 0-9 to character '0'-'9'
 mov ah, 0xA      ;Append newline
 mov [ecx], ax

 mov ecx, sum
 call print_int
```