# Writing a program that loops doing user input until one of two conditions are met

Tags: linux, loops, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm new to learning NASM Assembly. I keep running into two different problems. Either the program keeps looping or it would stop after the first input before any conditions are met.

I want to get the user to give an input and for the program to keep looping until the total sum of all input is greater than 9 or till the user enters a 0.

```
section .data
    ask db 'Enter a number between 1 and 9, or 0 to exit: ', 0Ah
    ask_len equ $ - ask

section .bss
    total resb 4
    input resb 1

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Initialize total to 0
    mov al, '0'
    mov [total], al

input_loop:
    ; Use SYS_WRITE to print the prompt
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, ask
    mov edx, ask_len
    int 80h

    ; Use SYS_READ to read a single character into input
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, input
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h

    ; Check if input == '0', if yes, exit the loop
    cmp byte [input], '0'
    je exit_loop

    ; Convert ASCII character to numeric value
    sub byte [input], '0'

    ; Load current total into al
    mov al, [total]

    ; Add input to al
    add al, [input]

    ; Check if result is greater than '9', if yes, exit the loop
    cmp al, '9'
    jg exit_loop

    ; Store the result back in total
    mov [total], al
    
    ; Convert the final resul
    add byte [total], '0'
    
    ; Unconditionally jump back to input_loop
    jmp input_loop

exit_loop:
    ; Use SYS_WRITE to print the total
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, [total]
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h

    ; Exit the program with code 0
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80
```

Comment: `cmp al, '9'` should be `cmp al, 9`. It's a number, not a character code.

Comment: @Barmar I still cannot get my code to properly loop. I have tried inputs 0 through 10 but the program ends after the first input. Also it does not output the total sum of the inputs.

Comment: The scheme of adding `0` to convert a number to ASCII only works for single digits (0-9).  Since in your case, the total sum exceeds 9, you need to do more work; e.g. divide by 10 and use the quotient and remainder as your two digits, adding `0` to each one.

Comment: Another issue is that when standard input is a terminal, it is line buffered.  So your program won't do anything until enter is pressed.  And when it is, your program will read a newline character `\n` which I don't think you handle correctly.

Comment: I would recommend the following as a warmup: write the program in C, using no library functions except `read()` and `write()`.  Currently you're trying to learn a lot of general low-level programming concepts *and* assembly language at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ; Use SYS_READ to read a single character into input
> mov eax, 3
> mov ebx, 0
> mov ecx, input
> mov edx, 1
> int 80h
> ```

You should not forget the newline character that you get from pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Better define `input resb 2` and ask for 2 bytes via `mov edx, 2`. You still process the byte at `byte [input]`.

> ```
> ; Store the result back in total
> mov [total], al
> ; Convert the final resul
> add byte [total], '0'                        <<< wrong
> ; Unconditionally jump back to input_loop
> jmp input_loop
> ```

You made the choice to initialize the *total* variable to the **character** '0'. That's fine up to the point where you store it back to memory. But then you erroneously add another '0' in order to convert into character something that is already a character.

> ```
> ; Check if result is greater than '9', if yes, exit the loop
> cmp al, '9'
> jg exit_loop
> ; Store the result back in total
> mov [total], al
> ```

Once the result in the AL register obeys the condition, you immediately jump to *exit_loop* where you (try to (1)) show the contents from the *total* variable, **but you did not update that variable with the latest value from AL**. The problem with this, is that IMO opinion this could be fine given the task description; it would certainly avoid having ever to display a 2-digit final result.
(1) About displaying the result, `mov ecx, [total]` fetches the character (plus 3 extra bytes) from memory where *SYS_WRITE* really expects from you a pointer to that character. Just loose the square brackets.

```
section .data
    ask db 'Enter a number between 1 and 9, or 0 to exit: ', 0Ah
    ask_len equ $ - ask

section .bss
    total resb 4
    input resb 2

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Initialize total to '0' plus a newline
    mov eax, 00000A30h

input_loop:
    mov [total], eax

    ; Use SYS_WRITE to print the prompt
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, ask
    mov edx, ask_len
    int 80h

    ; Use SYS_READ to read a single character into input
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, input
    mov edx, 2
    int 80h

    ; Check if input == '0', if yes, exit the loop
    cmp byte [input], '0'
    je exit_loop

    ; Convert ASCII character to numeric value [1,9]
    sub byte [input], '0'
    mov eax, [total]
    add al, [input]

    ; Check if result is greater than '9', if yes, exit the loop
    cmp al, '9'
    jng input_loop

exit_loop:
    ; Use SYS_WRITE to print the 1-digit total plus a newline
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, total
    mov edx, 2
    int 80h

    ; Exit the program with code 0
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80
```

Input:
<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
<kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
<kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Output: 8

A very similar solution at [Adding 2 inputted numbers in Assembly using NASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289253/adding-2-inputted-numbers-in-assembly-using-nasm). Here you can learn how to display the result if it could contain 2 digits...